# Set all <img> tags size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I set each `<img>` tag to have a `style="width: 50px;"` or `width="50"`?

---

https://jsfiddle.net/wbu5qc0o

```
<div id="blog">
    <div class="content">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/fUty9h8.jpg" />
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/fUty9h8.jpg" />
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/fUty9h8.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>

<script type="application/javascript">
    var images = document.getElementById("blog").getElementsByClassName("content")[0].getElementsByTagName("img")[0];

    if (images) {
        for (i = 0; i < images.length; ++i) {
            images[i].style.width = '50px';
        }
    }
</script>
```

---

Without loop only the first image is affected

https://jsfiddle.net/6d7x5w2m/

```
images.style.width = '50px';
```

---

I've also tried with jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#blog .content img').each(function(){
      $(this).width(50);
   })
})
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're not just doing it with css? I.e  : `#blog .content>img{width:50px}`

Comment: @JonP Actually you're right, I think I could just use css. I overthought the solution to the problem. But I will still look at these answers as I might need the js to affect other tags attributes the same way.

Answer (score 2):

There are number of ways to do this but **if you just remove the `[0]` from `.getElementsByTagName('img')[0]`.It will work with your java-script code**

**1. Javascript**

```
var images = document.getElementById("blog").getElementsByClassName("content")[0].getElementsByTagName('img');
```

```js
var images = document.getElementById("blog").getElementsByClassName("content")[0].getElementsByTagName('img'); 


    if (images) {
        for (i = 0; i < images.length; ++i) {
            images[i].style.width = '50px';
        }
    }
```

```html
<div id="blog">
  <div class="content">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/fUty9h8.jpg" />
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/fUty9h8.jpg" />
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/fUty9h8.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

**2. Jquery**

```js
$('#blog img').width(50);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="blog">
      <div class="content">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/fUty9h8.jpg" />
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/fUty9h8.jpg" />
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/fUty9h8.jpg" />
      </div>
    </div>
```

**3. Using CSS**

```css
#blog .content>img{width:50px}
```

```html
<div id="blog">
      <div class="content">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/fUty9h8.jpg" />
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/fUty9h8.jpg" />
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/fUty9h8.jpg" />
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Why iterate twice with `$('#blog').find('img')` when it can be simplified to `$('#blog img')`?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this like following :-

```js
$('img').css('width', 50);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="blog">
  <div class="content">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/fUty9h8.jpg" />
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/fUty9h8.jpg" />
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/fUty9h8.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think it will replace the width of all images in the html page.Should be some selector as OP focus in question

Answer (score 1):

You can use [document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to do this.

```
var images = document.querySelectorAll("img");
```

Below is working code:

```js
var images = document.querySelectorAll("img");
imageArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(images);

imageArray.forEach(function(img) {
  img.style.width = '50px';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="blog">
  <div class="content">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/fUty9h8.jpg" />
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/fUty9h8.jpg" />
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/fUty9h8.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/z9uL6xvr/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this task using the [`NodeList.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) method:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('#blog > .content > img').forEach(image => {
  image.style.width = '50px';
});
```

```html
<div id="blog">
  <div class="content">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/fUty9h8.jpg">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/fUty9h8.jpg">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/fUty9h8.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```